# Android PreferenceActivity without subscreens

Tags: java, android, navigation, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I just added PreferenceActivity to my project in Android studio (auto generated) and I noticed, that my preferences navigation has subscreens. Instead of simple list with header categories (all inside single activity window), I'm getting my headers as simple list, then I need to click on item to get content displayed.

I don't want it, I need only simple preference screen without any navigation, with headers displayed as category label.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `PreferenceActivity` code like this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    }

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            } else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };


    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

}
```

**XML File:**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:settings="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
    <!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="primary_category"
        android:title="Category 1">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="coffee_file"
        android:title="EditText 1"
        android:defaultValue="Value of EditText 1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="secondary_category"
        android:title="Category 2">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="gin_file"
            android:title="EditText 2"
        android:defaultValue="Value of EditText 2"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:capitalize="words"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: This api is deprecated, isn't there any possibility to use modern api but without navigation?